# GlPaint not accepting my image for brush

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es

Ok I'm not sure how much details I can really give, but I'm having a crazy weird problem. I'm using the GLPaint code in my app from Apple, and the PaintingView.m code is the same exact code from Apple-nothing else. Yesterday, everything was working fine and the brush image for the paint was a circular particle that came with the GLPaint, and it was working fine.

Now, out of nowhere, the particle is just a square, and a square particle means that the GLPaint app can't find my particle-meaning if I just put any file name into here: brushImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Particle.png"].CGImage; I'll get a square particle.

So this is something wrong. However, I just have no idea why. I tried replacing the Particle.png image over again and placing it in different places in my Xcode project but that didn't work. I know it's a long shot, but does anyone have ANY possible ideas as to why this could happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have replaced Particle.png with an image that is not square, and the sides are not a power of two, then it will not work. For instance, the particle image can be 32x32, or 64x64, but not 110x110.

As for debugging, I would suggest **putting a breakpoint** at the line after `brushImage = [UIImage imageNamed...]`, and check the value of `brushImage`. If you are not comfortable using the debugger, just throw `NSLog(@"%p", brushImage)` right under that line. If the image is `nil`, or `0x0`, then you know that the image file cannot be found or decoded. If it is not, then the problem is in the code, not the setup.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but I did get a valid memory address for the NSLog, so I'm not sure what it is then :(

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured out the problem and I'll post the solution just in case anyone ever has an issue like this. Turns out I had a duplicate painting view in IB that for some reason maybe confused the painting view class. All I had to do was delete one of the views, then everything worked fine again.